# Getting error- Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, laravel, object

Code- 
(I'm getting "Trying to get property of non-object" on the line just above < form >)

```
//var_dump($tenants);
foreach($tenants as $rows){
            foreach($rows as $row) { //var_dump($row); die('..here now..');
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td data-field='name'><?php echo $row->name; ?></td>
                <td data-field='officecode'><?php echo $row->officecode; ?></td>
                <td>
                    <form method="post" action="/distributor/delete">
```

I do a var_dump of **$row** right inside the second foreach loop, and get these values->

```
object(stdClass)#174 (9) { ["accountManager"]=> NULL ["hasChildren"]=> bool(false) ["name"]=> string(11) "Easy123.com" ["officecode"]=> string(7) "RFDUK-2123 ["active"]=> int(0) ["id"]=> int(4) ["countryStatus"]=> NULL ["parentId"]=> NULL ["groupCode"]=> NULL }
```

$tenants is as follows->

```
object(stdClass)#210 (2) { ["tenants"]=> array(13) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#174 (9) { ["accountManager"]=> NULL ["hasChildren"]=> bool(false) ["name"]=> string(11) "Easy123.com" ["officecode"]=> string(7) "RFDUK-2123" ["active"]=> int(0) ["id"]=> int(4) ["countryStatus"]=> NULL
```

I'm confused because if I'm able to get **$row** value with a var_dump, then why not when I use **$row->name** inside the foreach loop?

Comment: "on the line just above < form >"  No, that's most definitely not the line the error is on.

Comment: how did you arrive at the tenants variable, lets see that code

Comment: can you put this code right under foreach($rows as $row) {

if(!isset($row->name) || !isset($row->officecode)) print_r($row);

Comment: @PatrickQ That is exactly where this tells me this is.

Comment: @spartyboy tenants variable is being sent from a controller file; I did a var_dump on this blade.php and it gets the value fine.

Comment: @Moe - gives me the same error. (I placed that in place of the var_dump I had inside the second foreach)

Comment: Error reporting does not say something like "The error is on the line above <form>".  It gives you a specific line number.  In the code you gave above, the " line just above < form >" is `<td>`.  I can 100% guarantee that the error is not on that line.  So either you are giving inaccurate error information, or the code you're providing is inaccurate.  You need to be as precise as possible, otherwise it is quite hard for us to help you.

Comment: @manishk i want to see how you sent it at d controller or the query used only then can we find a reasonable solutioon

Comment: @PatrickQ It actually said line 47 and because I dont have line numbers here I wrote it as the line above < form >, which is < td >. I know its strange and shouldn't have been that way.

Comment: Please put the exact, entire error message in the body of your question, along with the first 50 lines of the file mentioned in the error message. Make sure the contents of the file is _unchanged_ from when the error message was generated.

Comment: I'll remember that from next time. Thanks guys. I've got the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$tenants` is an object, with the property `tenants`. So, let's iterate it:

```
foreach($tenants->tenants as $row) {
?>
    <tr>
        <td data-field='name'><?php echo $row->name; ?></td>
         ...
```

Answer (score 1):

That error, "Trying to get property of non-object", usually occurs when you THINK you have an object, but you don't, and you end up trying to incorrectly treat a variable as if it's an object. For example:

```
$object1 = new Foo();
$object2 = new Foo();
$object3 = null;
$arrayOfObjects = array($object1, $object2, $object3);

foreach($arrayOfObjects as $object)
{
  echo $object->Bar;
}
```

When you're debugging, you probably end up seeing data for the first two objects in your loop, but then the 3rd array element is a null, not an object, so you'd get that error. And since you see data from the other elements, you THINK that the code is working.

And yes, the code works when all of the data is correct, but if there's any chance that your array doesn't contain an object... then you run into problems.

For example, let's say that your $rows array comes from data that is JSON-decoded:

```
$rows[] = json_decode("...row data...");
$rows[] = json_decode("...row data...");
$rows[] = json_decode("...row data...");
```

...and let's say that the JSON decode fails for whatever reason (bad JSON or something) and instead of giving you an object, it gives you a null. That will end up causing your echo $row->name; code to fail because $row will be null.

The QUICK fix is to just check is_object() before using it:

```
foreach($rows as $row) {
if(!is_object($row)) { continue; } // Skip non-object rows
```

...but you should really figure out what the data problem is to make sure you're not ignoring a bigger data problem.

Comment: This is nice debugging information, but doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: Wow I can't believe I didn't figure it out on my own but your example helped me to determine my issue perfectly. I kept making the mistake of var_dump in a loop.

Comment: @PatrickQ - Sure it does. The question was why they were getting that error when they were trying to access what they thought was a valid object. My very first paragraph explains that.

Comment: @Taylorj.Eke - Glad to hear it. Don't forget to upvote. :)

Comment: Great answer for less obvious issues (an object of mine was null, I was confused because I was sure it was an object).